# No build icon next to the build job list in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, permissions

I have a problem with one of my coworkers is not able to see the build icon next to each job. I already tried to make the permissions in `Manage Jenkins -> Configure Settings -> Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy` to be the same as mine but I can see the icon and my coworker can't, so any help would be appreciated.

I'm attaching a picture so everyone knows what I'm talking about. It's the red square box that my co-worker is not able to see.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your colleague has the `Job->Build` permission for those jobs, log out, clear cache in browser for jenkins, log in. It's possible their browser has an old version of the page cached or their client hasn't responded to a permissions change yet?

Comment: Thank you @Peter I told my colleague to log in using incognito mode, because I know in that mode cache is disabled. In any case just to make sure I didn't overlook that option where is the Job->Build permission setting?

Comment: Depending on whether you have `Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy` or `Matrix-based security ` enabled, it will either be in the `Configure` option on the left hand side for the job, or in the `configure global security` option in the Jenkins Admin Panel. If you feel my answer has answered your question please accept it and upvote.

Comment: I think that's what I already tried and I explained that I did in my question right?

Comment: Yeah it was, was just putting that there because I was listing out all possible causes. If you feel my answer has answered your question please accept it and upvote

Comment: unfortunately I can't accept that answer because that's basically repeating what I already tried and it hasn't solve my problem, so I will wait to see if someone else has another answer that solves my problem. If I do accept your answer everyone looking at my question would assume that it fixed my problem and won't try to help me.